# Check whether mode is on emacs

Tags: emacs, mode

How to check whether in the current buffer a mode is on?

I tried this for LaTeX, for which I wanted to have an align function align on `&`, but only if  I am in a LaTeX buffer, not in an ESS mode buffer.

How to do a check for this? I tried:

`(if (equal reftex-mode t) (message "TRUE"))`

and

`(if (equal LaTeX-mode t) (message "TRUE"))`

but reftex is set globally and LaTeX stuff does not work at all. Ideas?

Also, how to prevent the error "void variable" in the case these variables are not initiated?

Comment: `boundp` is the way to check for void variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Test against the "major-mode" variable:

```
(defun a-function()
    (if (eq major-mode 'latex-mode)
        (message "LaTeX mode is ON")
      (message "LaTeX mode is OFF")))
```

Comment: Great, Dan, happy to see a new Emacs hacker around here :)))

Comment: Can we apply this for minor modes?